# RSS feed for notable astronomical phenomena?

Tags: amateur-observing

For a long time I have been searching for a weekly [RSS feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) similar to the German-speaking [astronews.com](http://astronews.com) which features a few astronomical phenomena one could observe with amateur equipment, and a few highlights of recent professional observations.

Using search engines, you find dozens of sites like this, but they usually overlap, or are very pop-science, or are missing the recent observations. In practice, I am having too many newsletters and feeds to screen through, so maybe somebody else already has the same issue, and could help out.

**I am looking for low-traffic RSS newsfeed from creditable sources which compiles a few forecasted observation tips (e.g. for central Europe) and selected new top-notch observations from major telescopes of any wavelength, e.g. Hubble or [ESO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Southern_Observatory).**

In case that rings a bell: I am thinking about something similar to the two pages which appeared monthly in the former German science magazine *Kosmos* (see e.g. [German wiki entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_(Zeitschrift))), I will try to find a picture to illustrate it.

Comment: none of these qualify as "low-traffic RSS newsfeed": [Is there a standardized “Astronomical Alert” system?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32778/7982) and [“Who saw” the binary neutron star merger first? What was the sequence of events? (GRB/GW170817)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23187/7982) and [Does the Zwicky Transient Facility only run when triggered by a cell phone?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31761/7982) and [Will LSST make a significant increase in the rate of astronomical event alerts?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32777/7982)

Comment: and [Which observatories help NASA find 5 new asteroids per day?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18900/7982) but they illustrate the challenge posed by trying to funnel down the rate of astronomical discovery into a ow-traffic RSS newsfeed that will not miss the good stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site might help you: [In-The-Sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/). You can find RSS feed in the right panel. Its features are icons for amateur difficulty (from naked eye to advanced telescope), and not too much new ideas for observation as you wanted. Unfortunately, it doesn't feature recent professional observation as you stated, but I advise you to search another site for that. (So that you have one RSS for amateur ideas and one for recent professionals.)

Comment: in-the-sky.org rocks! It's one of my all-time favorite websites, incredibly useful.